# How do I verify origin between WordPress and a Chrome extension communication?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension, wordpress

I have a Chrome extension That uses the WordPress login to authenticate users, how do I verify that only the extension is making the request to the server and not anything or any other origin?

Comment: that's not possible to make hack proof

Comment: If you have access to both, you could just sign the body with some secret password and check for this on both sites (e.g. hash_hmac())

Comment: @Jan that would work, except Chrome extensions are usually JavaScript, so the key would have to be in plain-text in the source of the extension

Comment: Yes, I have access to both. @Jan Interesting idea where do I start to investigate this direction. Maybe if the extension could create a unique token that only works if it matches to the receiving end. Would it be complicated to create something like that?